# Find Min Max of 2D array in scala

Tags: scala, matrix, max

I have a 2D array of the form:

```
scala> signature_matrix
res129: Array[Array[Int]]
```

How do I find the maximum element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flatten to a 1d list, then call max:

```
arr.flatten.max
```

Answer (score 1):

```
signature_matrix.map(_.max).max
```

find sub `Array` max firstly and map to an `Array`, and find **max** again.